# Can I configure VLC to automatically organize my music library like iTunes does?

Tags: itunes, vlc-media-player, mp3, music, metadata

iTunes has the "keep iTunes music files organized" option, which automatically uses the metadata to sort the music files into folders organized by artist and album.

Is there any way to do this in VLC? I've enabled the "media library", but it seems like it's more of a glorified playlist than a full-featured media manager. Is there any way get the functionality (via plug-ins or whatever) of being able to edit track metadata (track name, artist, album) from within the media library and then have it be sorted into folders?